# How to convert a simple jquery to jquery function

Tags: jquery, function

I have the following code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clanname").keyup(function(e) {

            var clanname = $(this).val();
            if (clanname.length < 4) {
                $("#user-result").html('');
                return;
            }
        if (clanname.length >= 4) {
            $("#user-result").html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.get('getClanName', {clanname:clanname}, function(data) {   

                    if(data=='free')
                    {
                    $("#user-result").html('<img src="images/available.png" />');

                }else{
                    $("#user-result").html('<img src="images/not-available.png" />');
                }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

which I put in the head section of my php file, but I want to put this in a seperate .js file and want to call this code on the text changed event of my textbox.and I want to make it parameterized function and want to pass the textbox's text to that function Can somene please suggest me how to to this.

Comment: Put your code in fuction and call it when text change occur.

Answer (score 1):

1) Put following code in new doc:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   //your function 

});
```

2) Save this file as myfile.js

3) In php file put this reference:

```
<script src="path_to_jsfile_if_not_in_the_same_dir_as_phpfile/myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

create file like `custom.js` and paste this code in that file and save

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clanname").keyup(function(e) {

            var clanname = $(this).val();
            if (clanname.length < 4) {
                $("#user-result").html('');
                return;
            }
        if (clanname.length >= 4) {
            $("#user-result").html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.get('getClanName', {clanname:clanname}, function(data) {   

                    if(data=='free')
                    {
                    $("#user-result").html('<img src="images/available.png" />');

                }else{
                    $("#user-result").html('<img src="images/not-available.png" />');
                }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

In your page below `<head>` & below Jquery library js file add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention one thing- I want to make it parameterized function and want to pass the textbox's text to that function